# how can i do add two number in java using proxy pattern

Tags: java

I am trying to do a very simple code to add two numbers in java using proxy pattern. so I use the code bellow:

**Proxyex class**

```
public class Proxyex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a,b;
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
       a = sc.nextInt();
       b = sc.nextInt();

        proxy  px = new proxy ();
       System.out.println(px.add(a, b));

    }

}
```

**Subject  class**

```
public abstract class Subject {
    public abstract int add (int a,int b);

}
```

**Concrete class**

```
public class Concrete extends Subject {

    @Override
    public int add(int a, int b) {
      return a+b;  
    }

}
```

**proxy  class**

```
public class proxy extends Subject{
    Concrete cs;

    @Override
    public int add(int a,int b) {
        return a+b;

      }
    }
```

can you guys help me

Comment: What problem did you encounter?

Comment: proxy as i mention

Comment: Well, KSwally, put 'int x = 5 +2; // I did some addition, me!' in there somewhere. That answers your question as stated. But that seems like a silly answer; hopefully this shows you why neither I nor @donquih0te understands what you're really asking here.

Comment: what is the problem in your code? please ask a specific question

Comment: i am trying to use proxy pattern in this code you have to do something in Subject class that is what i know

Comment: Since no one understands what you want exactly,
You can check this video will explain to you what is and how to implement proxy design pattern:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHg5bWW4nUI

Comment: @AMA i will check it out thank you

Comment: @Bashir use proxy pattern to add two numbers

Comment: some points:
Your cs.dosome(); in proxy class throws a npe as the cs is null;
You should instanciate it and then add some logic in the dosome() in Concrete class? like System.out.print(2+3);

Comment: @Kostakiiiis + i change the method fom dosome to add

 and i tried this in proxy add method  a = sc.nextInt();
        b = sc.nextInt();  
         s = a + b;
         System.out.print(s);

and this on subject class 
int a, b, s;
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

Comment: @KSwally can you post the updated code? It's easier to understand what you mean this way.

Comment: @Kostakiiiis okay check it out

Comment: The proxy class shouldn't perform the calculation, it should call the method in the real class instead and return the result it gets from that method

Comment: @JoakimDanielson so what i did is not the right way to use proxy ? , okay i will try yours